# CNN inference is slow on Jetson Nano

Tags: keras, cnn, performance

I'm running what I believe is a pretty lightweight CNN on an nVidia Jetson Nano with Jetpack 4.4.
[nVidia claims the Nano can run a ResNet-50 at 36fps](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-nano-dl-inference-benchmarks), so I expected my much smaller network to run at 30+ fps with ease.

Actually though, each forward pass takes 160-180ms, so I score 5-6 fps at best. At production predictions have to be made real-time on a live camera stream, so improving the per-sample-performance by using batches > 1 is not an option.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my inference code? Am I wrong thinking the network architecture should be pretty fast to compute compared to e.g. ResNet-50? What can I do to find out what exactly takes so much time?

My CNN:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 210, 848, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 210, 282, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 102, 138, 16)      2368
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 51, 69, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 33, 32)        12832
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 16, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 6, 64)          51264
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 3, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 384)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 384)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                24640
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
elu (ELU)                    (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65
=================================================================
Total params: 91,169
Trainable params: 91,169
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model_name = 'v9_small_FC_epoch_3'
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('/home/jetson/notebooks/trained_models/' + model_name + '.h5')
loaded_model.summary()
frame = cv2.imread('/home/jetson/notebooks/frame1.jpg')    
test_data = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    predictions = loaded_model.predict(test_data)
    print(predictions[0][0])
    end = time.time()
    print("Inference took {}s".format(end-start))
```

Result:

```
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 10.111131191253662s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1822071075439453s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.17330455780029297s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.18085694313049316s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.16646790504455566s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1703803539276123s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1788337230682373s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.17131853103637695s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.1660606861114502s
4.7763316333293915
Inference took 0.18377089500427246s
```

**Edit:** To make sure I'm not just underestimating my network, I replaced it with one that just consists of a single output and a single output neuron. As expected the initial loading of the model is significantly faster, but after that, inference is almost as slow.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 1, 1, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1, 1, 1)           2         
=================================================================
Total params: 2
Trainable params: 2
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
2021-01-06 20:44:22.361558: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
Inference took 1.9230175018310547s
Inference took 0.17112112045288086s
Inference took 0.16610288619995117s
Inference took 0.1768038272857666s
Inference took 0.16962003707885742s
Inference took 0.16416263580322266s
Inference took 0.17536258697509766s
Inference took 0.16603755950927734s
Inference took 0.16376280784606934s
Inference took 0.16828060150146484s
```

On my Desktop (i5-2500k, GTX 1070Ti) even the first prediction takes just around 26ms:

```
Inference took 0.02569293975830078s
Inference took 0.026061534881591797s
Inference took 0.023118019104003906s
Inference took 0.023060083389282227s
Inference took 0.02504444122314453s
Inference took 0.02664470672607422s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like converting to TensorRT improves performance by more than 10x (!) for me, which I didn't expect at all.

The downside is, loading the TensorRT model takes >2min now and for reasons I can't grasp the script eats 2.2G of memory. Also getting the conversion process to work was beyond painful. I'm gonna open a new Q&A on that topic, because it seems a lot of people eventually give up on it.

The TensorRT model seems to need a bit of warmup (~100 passes) and then settles at the final inference speed, which in my case is ~15-17ms (68-66fps). Pretty amazing improvement I have to say.

```
Inference took 100.2991828918457s
Inference took 0.2558176517486572s
Inference took 0.04433894157409668s
Inference took 0.037764787673950195s
Inference took 0.03640627861022949s
Inference took 0.04129934310913086s
Inference took 0.024821043014526367s
Inference took 0.0219266414642334s
...
Inference took 0.0170745849609375s
Inference took 0.016851186752319336s
Inference took 0.016122817993164062s
Inference took 0.01502084732055664s
Inference took 0.015442371368408203s
Inference took 0.01560211181640625s
```

Without TensorRT, not only did inference take much longer in general, there were also occasional passes that took even longer, up to 750ms in some cases. For real-time applications that's a deal breaker.

With TensorRT the inference times are pretty stable, I didn't see more than 15% variation within 10K passes.